# Disable zoom google maps não funciona

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Implementei um `iframe` com um mapa do Google Maps, o problema é que eu queria desativar o *scrool zoom* e o *drag*. Já tentei este código dentro e fora da função jQuery e não resulta:

HTML:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

JS:

```
var mapOptions = {
     zoom: 17, 
    draggable: false,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    zoomControl: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
```

Comment: Ainda não tenho uma resposta definitiva, mas segundo meu entendimento [dessa pergunta no SOEN](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7844124/520779) isso **não** é possível se seu mapa está usando `embed`.

Comment: Qual seria a alternativa? Obgado

Comment: Tente esta solução: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992498/disable-mouse-scroll-wheel-zoom-on-embedded-google-maps acredito que resolverá seu problema. []'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui vai um código completo que funciona o bloqueio do zoom:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="pt,BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>API Google Maps V3</title>

        <!-- Inicialização do mapa -->
        <script>
        function initialize() {

      // Exibir mapa;
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-8.0631495, -34.87131120000004);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: myLatlng,
        panControl: false, 
    draggable: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        scrollwheel: false,
        // mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
          mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
        }
      }
      // Exibir o mapa na div #mapa;
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), mapOptions);

      // crio um objeto passando o array de estilos (styles) e definindo um nome para ele;
      var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {
        name: "Mapa Style"
      });
      // Aplicando as configurações do mapa
      map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
      map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

    }

    // Função para carregamento assíncrono
    function loadScript() {
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDeHb17So0QupSGO_d6b8X-OyvJ32UQehs&sensor=true&callback=initialize";
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    window.onload = loadScript;
    </script>

        <style>
            #mapa{
                width: 100%;
                height: 500px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="mapa"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Serviu pra você cara?

Comment: De qualquer jeito obrigado.

Comment: Resultou obgado

Answer (score 2):

Segundo [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22012725/520779) e [esse comentário](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844124/disable-map-controls-in-google-maps-embed#comment18151802_7846901) no SOEN, não é possível customizar o comportamento dos mapas utilizados no modo `embed`. Seu problema parece ser que você está tentando fazer as duas coisas ao mesmo tempo: inserir o mapa num `iframe` (embed) e criá-lo a partir da API JavaScript.

Experimente substituir seu `iframe` por uma `div` comum, vazia:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

E em seguida usar seu código tal como está:

```
var mapOptions = {
    //zoom: 17,
    draggable: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
}
map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
```

Você terá de colocar parâmetros adicionais para especificar **onde** está sendo mapeado, mas as funções da API devem funcionar normalmente nesse modo (não sei dizer se o `zoom` é mermo necessário, ou se ele admite um valor padrão, então estou incluindo ele aqui comentado).

Comment: Onde coloco esses parametros (link do google maps)? dsculpe a ignorancia muito obgado

Comment: var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

Comment: @Miguel Infelizmente eu também não tenho muita experiência com essa API, então não sei te informar. [Esse tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) (em inglês) tem algumas informações, mas não todas. A chave aqui é que você não faz um "link" pro google maps, você deixa a própria API criar esse link pra você. Tudo o que você passa são parâmetros. Mas quais são todos os parâmetros disponíveis, isso eu não sei dizer... Se você está usando coordenadas, um deles é fácil: `center: { lat:39.139547, lng:-8.900489 }` (isso vai junto dos `mapOptions`).

Answer (score 0):

Para você colocar que controle do zoom  é falso, antes você terá que especificar qual a porcetagem do zoom desejado.

```
 var mapOptions = {
     zoom: 17, //Por exemplo
     draggable: false,
     zoomControl: false,
     scrollwheel: false,
 }
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

 $(document).ready(function() {...
```

Tente assim:

```
 map.getMinimumResolution=function() { 
   return 17; 
 }; 

 map.getMaximumResolution=function() { 
    return 17; 
 };
```

Se não funcionar tente acrescentar isso:

```
scaleControl: false,

map.disableScrollWheelZoom();
```

Comment: Fiz o update em cima e upload da pagina com essa dica mas não resolveu. Obgado

Comment: Esta resposta é mesmo resposta ou foi um comentário?